# React Native problems with gradle tool

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, gradle, native

When I run `gradlew clean` inside my react native project I get the following error:

> Value 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid).

I am just able to run `gadlew clean` inside my android directory in my react native project and I'm using windows 10.

Below are my configurations:

- `JAVA_HOME:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211`
- `Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin`
- `Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin`

I already tried to change my `gradle.properties` file which is inside the android directory with the following:

> org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211

After I do this it still does not work and my java is running normally because when I type `java -version` I can see the version of java I'm using. The version is: `1.8.0_211`

Does anyone one knows how to fix this?!

Comment: set `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211`;

Comment: Possibly confusion between local gradlew (through gradlew.bat) and system wide gradle. In the latter case look for the configuration of the system wide gradle, but it is probably not going to find your `build.gradle` file anyway.

Comment: sorry my `JAVA_PATH` under user variables was already like: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211`. I just fixed this in my post right now

Comment: I don't even have this directory anymore: `'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201`

Comment: where do I find configuration of the system wide gradle?

Comment: make sure your `JAVA_HOME` is correct. then remove the line `org.gradle.java.home` from gradle.properties then run again.

Comment: My `JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211` and I removed `org.gradle.java.home` from `gradle.properties` and still getting the same error

Comment: does anyone has a clue on how to solve this?

Comment: I think maybe is something with another installation of gradle